# How to link a mysql record and a MongoDB document?

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, mongoengine

My web app uses both mysql and MongoDB (for storing documents with flexible schema). I need to  link a DB record to a Mongo document. I am not sure what is the best approach.

I am planning to use a VARCHAR field in the mysql table to store the document id. But I found the id in Mongo is like: `ObjectId("53aa792c90b638702c92eeca")`. What is this id? Can I convert it to a string and store it in mysql like a foreign key?

I am using [MongoEngine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/) as the python wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ObjectId's can be converted to strings most simplly by wraping it in str().  Eg:

```
str(ObjectId("53aa792c90b638702c92eeca"))
```

Then you can store it in your VARCHAR column.

Answer (score 1):

The object id is a 12-byte unique binary value.  The shell just displays it using the ObjectID("...") notation.  Whichever way you store it, whether as true binary or as a hex string in a VARCHAR, you should be able to find the corresponding document with an appropriate query.